# How to post dto data to a webservice with ajax/jquery on asp

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I wish you a happy new year.

I'm trying to built a Jquery dialog modal form to create new users, for an admin console, on asp.net page. The objective is to send the form data to a webservice which related to a DTO and a stored procedure. I don't understand why I get an internal server error, when I try to post my form to my webservice. My web access is strongly filtered, so it's not easy to search (on stack I don't have any css).

Could you give some helps to solve this problem ?

Thanks for any help

The Webservice :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

    [WebMethod]
    public static string InsertData(Users users)
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            connect.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "InsertUser";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", users.login);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", users.fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", users.lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", users.password);
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
            return "succes";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

The aspx.page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnsubmit').click(function() {
        var myData = "{'login':'"+$("[id$='logintxt']").val() +"' , 'fname':'"+$("[id$='fnametxt']").val() +"' , 'lname':'"+$("[id$='lnametxt']").val() +"' , 'password':'"+$("[id$='passwordtxt']").val() +"')";
        SendNewUser(myData);
        function SendNewUser(myData) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Webservice.asmx/InsertData",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "users": [myData] }),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',

                succes: function (result) {
                    alert("Record saved successfully !");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error function : " + XMLHttRequest.toString() + "\n\Status : " + textStatus + "\n\Error : " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

And the .asmx

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.cs" Class="WebService" %>
```

the users class

```
public class Users
{
    public string login {get;set;}
    public string fname {get;set;}
    public string lname {get;set;}
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked your code at couple of lines as below. See if that helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnsubmit').click(function() {
    /*Changed below line*/
    var myData = "[{'login':'"+$("[id$='logintxt']").val() +"' , 'fname':'"+$("[id$='fnametxt']").val() +"' , 'lname':'"+$("[id$='lnametxt']").val() +"' , 'password':'"+$("[id$='passwordtxt']").val() +"'}]";
    SendNewUser(myData);
    function SendNewUser(myData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Webservice.asmx/InsertData",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "'users': "+ myData }),  /*Changed this line*/
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            succes: function (result) {
                alert("Record saved successfully !");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error function : " + XMLHttRequest.toString() + "\n\Status : " + textStatus + "\n\Error : " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, After some research I've found a solution. I've made a mistake with the url of Webservice.